# Hypergeometric function $\,_1 F_1(0;0;x)$?

Tags: hypergeometric-function

What is $\,_1F_1(0;0;x)$? Since its first argument is $0$, either we say it is 0 or since its first and second arguments are equal we say it is $e^x$? I cannot understand.

Answer (score 1):

The function is constant:
$$
\,_1F_{1}(0;0;x) = 1
$$

The exponential form comes from 
$$
\,_1F_{1}(1;1;x) = e^{x}
$$

From [functions.wolfram.com](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric1F1/02/)

[image: excerpt]

Note the special case you ask about:

[image]

You have focused on a special case of $b=0$. From [WolframMathworl](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConfluentHypergeometricFunctionoftheFirstKind.html):

[image]

Comment: Thanks but how can we prove it?

Comment: @LİLA: Prove the 0 result or the exponential result?

Comment: Proof of the 0 result?